# How to split a long timeout API call into smaller ones

Tags: cron, serverless, vercel

I have an API js file which gets called by a cronjob via curl GET.

This js file basically makes a query to an external API via `await fetch` and saves some data from the response onto *MongoDB* via `await .. updateOne`. The problem is this happens in loop for about 500 different values and it takes more than 10 seconds to finish, whereas my server timeout limit for serverless functions is 10 sec.

So how can I split it into multiple "GET" requests ?
Isn't doing a `for loop` inside the API js file the same since it'd still count as a single operation?

Every time I Google for this via different keywords it finds me non-related stuff, am I missing something? maybe is rare to find such a case? I'm new to the whole cronjob/serverless functions thing, if this is not the correct place to ask for this please point me out where should I post it within Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Two potential solutions:

- <s>The brute force method would be to increase the [timeout setting](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#configuration), you can do this via the `serverless.yml`, either in the `provider` section or in the function definition directly. ([Maximum timeout for AWS Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/serverless-architectures-lambda/timeout.html) is 900 seconds or 15 minutes.)</s> (Not relevant as on Vercel, [timeout](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/limits) of 900 seconds for Enterprise and 60 seconds for Pro but 10 seconds for the free plan.)
- Doing the for loop inside the Lambda function wouldn't change much. If you can break it down into multiple cron jobs which you can parameterise. E.g. imagine a cron job which goes through a staff list to do some processing on a daily basis. You could change your cron job to accept a range of letters which filters the staff list by last name. So instead of one cron job you would do four: *A-F*, *G-M*, *N-S* and *T-Z*. (In your case trying to find a parameter which splits the 500 values into equal sized buckets.)

As you get billed by duration and memory consumption with serverless (at least with AWS) it probably doesn't make a lot of sense to split it so increasing the timeout setting might be the easier solution, but I don't know your full context so this is just a guess.

Comment: Regarding the timeout settings you mentioned, what service are you referring to? My server right now is on Vercel, and on a free plan they only allow cron operations of max 10sec

Comment: Oh I thought you're using the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/). Then the timeout increase the way I described it doesn't apply and you'll need to split your call into multiple cron jobs.

Comment: I was thinking based on the split method suggested, to create multiple crons with a GET like http:..../myjsfile.js?letter=a-d and then inside myjsfile.js I go check the ?= params, query all the 500 from the db but then make API calls only for names starting with a,b,c and d

Comment: Yes that should work, if possible even try to avoid getting all the 500 from the database and select only the relevant according to the `param` you sent, e.g. just the `a-d` ones in this case (but this highly depends how your db schema looks like and so on).